# changing the assembly title

Tags: c#, file-association

I changed the assembly title of WPF-application from "Name1" to "Name2".

Files with extension ".sct" associate with this application.

I use RegistryKey. I associate file extension with application each time the application runs:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Classes", true);
    key.CreateSubKey("." + extension).SetValue(string.Empty, extension + "_auto_file");

    key = key.CreateSubKey(extension + "_auto_file");
    key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue(string.Empty, icon);

    key = key.CreateSubKey("Shell");
    key.SetValue(string.Empty, "Open");

    key = key.CreateSubKey("Open");

    key.CreateSubKey("Command").SetValue("", "" + applicationExecutablePath + " %1");
    ...
}
```

Now when I install application in default directory and open .sct file properties I see old application name "Name1" instead of "Name2".

But if I install the application in another directory then application name in file properties changes to "Name2".

Why does it happen?

Answer (score -1):

> I changed the assembly title of WPF-application from "Name1" to "Name2".

That is an assembly TITLE? Name?

> I use RegistryKey. I associate file extension with application each time the application runs:

Here we go, beginner mistakes and worst practices. Your prgoram may not have the rights for that. This should be done ONLY by an installer level, not by a user executing pgogram.

> Now when I install application in default directory and open .sct file properties I see old 
>   application name "Name1" instead of "Name2".

Also after a restart? See, the registry is likely cached and you dont run it from an installer. Ergo you see outdated values. Try restarting the compuer.

Comment: 1. I change the assembly title in "AssemblyInfo.cs". 2. You are right. I should associate file extension by an installer level. 3. I try to restart but it doesn't help.